# Corebluetooth or iBeacon, Is possible to get background faster?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I would like to coding with corebluetooth or iBeacon. But i do not know UUID of bluetooth. Is possible to get background faster?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "get background faster"?

Comment: If to get found new BLE device than should be show notification while app background. Here i tested showed notification after 5 min.

Comment: check this tutorial for [iBeacon programming](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-programming-ibeacons-tutorial/)

Comment: @pawan is avabile to put without UUDID?

Comment: what it mean? you want to program it without using  UUID?

Comment: @pawan yes, i want it. is available?

Comment: so without UUID , how you will communicate with other device ? i think you want to scan for all available iBeacon devices right?

Comment: @pawan yes, But Background app should be fast.

Comment: No, background detection is a function of the iOS ibeacon-specific APIs which require you to know the UUID(s) you want to look for.  There doesn't seem to be much of a question here, at least not one that you could not readily satisfy by looking at the numerous other iBeacon questions here.